# How can I fix an ssh error for my home server

Tags: server, wireless, ssh

I am on Windows and am trying to ssh into a ubuntu server device, it is my home server and the password is correct. after 3 attempts of the password Permission denied (publickey,password). comes up
is there any way to fix this? Edit I havnt fixed it and I dont think im on the exact same internet (I have an internet extender plugged into my modem and am on that network but my linux server is on my modems network) but I have decided to just do everything from the server manually but thankyou for the support for anyone who commentented.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1481255/edit) to show us how you determined the server's correct IP address. Also edit your question to specify if your Windows client is on the same home network, or elsewhere across the internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)